# How to provide pagename.tpl.php to specific page?

Tags: 7

I have basic knowledge of Drupal ,I know that if I am giving page name with .tpl.php file taht directly apply to that specific page .but to apply that I don't know so can you please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy this code to template.php (donot forget to change the **yourtheme** name)

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // Do we have a node?
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {

    // Ref suggestions cuz it's stupid long.
    $suggests = &$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'];

    // Get path arguments.
    $args = arg();
    // Remove first argument of "node".
    unset($args[0]);

    // Set type.
    $type = "page__type_{$vars['node']->type}";

    // Bring it all together.
    $suggests = array_merge(
      $suggests,
      array($type),
      theme_get_suggestions($args, $type)
    );

    // if the url is: 'http://domain.com/node/123/edit'
    // and node type is 'blog'..
    //
    // This will be the suggestions:
    //
    // - page__node
    // - page__node__%
    // - page__node__123
    // - page__node__edit
    // - page__type_blog
    // - page__type_blog__%
    // - page__type_blog__123
    // - page__type_blog__edit
    //
    // Which connects to these templates:
    //
    // - page--node.tpl.php
    // - page--node--%.tpl.php
    // - page--node--123.tpl.php
    // - page--node--edit.tpl.php
    // - page--type-blog.tpl.php          << this is what you want.
    // - page--type-blog--%.tpl.php
    // - page--type-blog--123.tpl.php
    // - page--type-blog--edit.tpl.php
    //
    // Latter items take precedence.
  }
}
```

all examples are inside the comment which format you should follow in side the template folder for creating tpl.php '%' is use for all, best of luck, 
note : don't forget to clear the cache
you can use [devel_themer](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module for specific suggestions of tpl's.