# Template suggestions for file_entity.tpl.php

Tags: 7, views, theming, entities, files

### Short version

My aim is to theme a file field in a view of node fields. In the view configuration, the field formatter is set to `Rendered file` and a view mode is selected. How do I suggest a template file?

### Long version

What I see is, theming of a file entity is done through file_entity.tpl.php in `file_entity` module. I copied this file to my theme folder and tried following names:

```
file_entity--my-view-mode.tpl.php
file-entity--my-view-mode.tpl.php
file_entity--views--my-view-mode.tpl.php
file-entity--views--my-view-mode.tpl.php
```

None worked. So I tried to hook in some suggestions like below as `view_mode_templates.module` also does.

```
<?php
MYTHEME_preprocess(&$vars){
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'file_entity__views__my_view_mode';
}
?>
```

This ends up loading that `file-entity--views--my-view-mode.tpl.php` but funnily I get an error like this:

> **Fatal error:** Only variables can be passed by reference in
>   **blah/blah/file-entity--views--my-view-mode.tpl.php on line 71**

Which is actually this line:

```
hide($content['links']);
```

Funnier thing is if I comment that line out, I get a fatality masterkill WSOD with no error message.

If I try to do it like below, again as `view_mode_templates.module` does, it doesn't see the suggestion.

```
<?php
function MYTHEME_preprocess(&$vars) {
  if (array_key_exists('file_entity', entity_get_info())) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'file_entity__views__my_view_mode';
  }
}
?>
```

So, does it maybe not suggest the theme suggestion in the correct place? Do I need to suggest this in something like `template_preprocess_file_entity(&$variables)` or `template_preprocess_entity(&$variables)`? Which don't have the appropriate `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions']` array as far as I couldn't see.

Any comment is hardcore appreciated, thanks.

Comment: 1.Are you trying to change the template of file-field (from Field module) or FileEntity default template (from File Entity module)? 2.If you are trying to override the default template of FileEntity, then did you clear the cache after you've copied it?

Comment: U need to follow http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95747/how-to-provide-pagename-tpl-php-to-specific-page/95749#95749 and for suggestions use the devel themer module.

Comment: 1. @xurshid29 I am trying to change the FileEntity default template from File Entity module. Going on with Filed module doesn't look possible as per [Issue: File entity views fields outputting as a link are broken](https://drupal.org/node/1858036). They are using the view modes for the file entities. 2. Yes I did, on each trial, more than twice.

Comment: @madhurjya thank you, but since what I am trying to theme is not a node but a file entity, can you please be a little more specific on the implementation?

Comment: above, are you actually calling `MYTHEME_preprocess()` or `MYTHEME_preprocess_file_entity()`?

Comment: @jimjamma I am calling MYTHEME_preprocess() as per [template_preprocess_file_entity | file_entity.module | Drupal 7 | DrupalContrib](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!file_entity!file_entity.module/function/template_preprocess_file_entity/7) the **$theme_hook_suggestions** array is not available in template_preprocess_file_entity.

Comment: @duru I have give you a link for suggestions of field templates, try to use that http://mtt.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/978785-how-to-name-field-templates-in-drupal-7-in-order-to-override-them as I previously told you to use the devel themer module for better suggestions.

Comment: I'm confused @duru in that theme_hook_suggestions are being set at the bottom of that link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a documentation about template suggestions at [Displaying Media](https://drupal.org/node/1793548) under the heading *Further Theming*.

> The theme suggestions provided by the File Entity module are:
>
> ```
> file__{file type}
> file__{file type}__{view mode}
> file__{mime type}
> file__{mime type}__{view mode}
> file__{file id}
> file__{file id}__{view mode}
> ```

Comment: God, I read that docs more than 10 times in the summer and now forgot what they were about. Thank you very much Елин Й.

Comment: The above listed formats are missing some underscores due to some editors issue, I couldn't fix. Please refer to the docs: https://drupal.org/node/1793548

Comment: I've corrected them changing the formatting from block quote to code block.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad that I could help you to solve your problem.

Comment: omg, after a year i was looking for the same thing and i googled it and came upon this, read it without knowing that it was mine. so funny:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an actual example for "document" file type:

```
file--document.tpl.php
file--document--default.tpl.php   // default view
file--application-pdf.tpl.php   // pdf mime type
file--application-pdf--default.tpl.php
file--1234.tpl.php   // file id
file--1234--default.tpl.php
```